# AJAX response is interpreted as string

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, string, google-visualization

In my code i have an AJAX call which returns an string like this:

```
['De Noordzeemoorden 3 Ritueel',-15,3190,'Pearson',47850,],
['The Galactic Mage (The Galactic Mage...',-15,254,'Pearson',3810,],
['How to Develop your ESP (English Edit...',-15,1839,'Thomson',27585,],
['Wat ons niet zal doden (Millennium Bo...',-13,2732,'Kluwer',35516,],
['All Dressed in White: An Under Suspic...',-11,527,'Kluwer',5797,],
['Wormhole (The Rho Agenda Book 3) (Eng...',-11,2535,'Kluwer',27885,],
['Separation of Power (A Mitch Rapp Novel)',-10,1726,'Pearson',17260,],
['A Banquet of Consequences: A Lynley N...',-9,3695,'Thomson',33255,],
['De Navigator',-9,2126,'Kluwer',19134,]
```

I want to use this response to draw a graph. I use this response in the function where i draw the graph. The problem is, that the result is interpreted as a string, which results in an error.

For example, when i copy paste the string above and put it in the function where the graph is drawn, it works like a charm.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If `typeof response` is `object` then parse it using `JSON.parse` and use that data in graph..

Comment: That isn't a string. It looks like some nested arrays (the outer array enclosure isn't seen). That would explain why the data works when you paste it into the function. We need to see more of your code to see how you are using it. The _relevant_ code, like the AJAX call and the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JSON.parse()` it converts a String to a JavaScript Object

Comment: __The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON__. converts :(

Comment: JSON.parse() gives me: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Because the data isn't JSON. Are you sure you're getting this via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string as an argument when the function is expecting a different type to be passed to it (probably an array or an object).

You should setup your AJAX request to respond with a string-encoded JSON object and then use `JSON.parse()` to retrieve a JavaScript object. You can then pass that object to your graph function or extract an array from that object and pass the array to your graph function.